# Why the correct operation result is not displayed in Intel x86 Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

Using Intel x86 Assembly Language, I want to display these lines which is about adding 2 numbers:

```
Enter val1: 4
Enter val2: 3
RESULT: 7
```

I wrote these instructions to get the values from user and perform the operation:

```
;start
.model  small
.stack  100h
.data

msg1     db      'enter val1: $' 
msg2     db      'enter val2: $' 
msg3 db 'result is: $'
val1 db ?
val2 db ?
result db ?

.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax   

;display msg1
lea dx, msg1
mov ah,09h
int 21h 

;get input val1
mov ah, 1
int 21h 
mov val1, al

;new line
mov dl, 0ah   
int 21h

;display msg2
lea dx, msg2
mov ah,09h
int 21h 

;get input val2
mov ah, 1
int 21h 
mov val2, al

;new line
mov dl, 0ah   
int 21h

;add process
mov al, val1
mov bl, val2
add al, bl
add al, 30h
mov result, al

;display msg3
lea dx, msg3
mov ah,09h
int 21h 

;display result
mov ah, 2
mov dl, result
int 21h

;end
mov   ah,4ch
int     21h
end
```

However, the output of `RESULT` I got is a strange value and I'm not really sure what is my mistake, because when I run it for subtraction with changing the first `add` instruction to `sub`, it works well:

```
Enter val1: 4
Enter val2: 3
RESULT: ǔ
```

what is the mistake?

Comment: In the `add process` section you need to convert ASCII codepoints to numbers. Add `sub bl, 30h` and `sub al, 30h` (which works only for single-digit numbers).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added these 2 lines but still got the same mistake

Comment: Where did you add the lines?

Comment: I tried at the beginning and also end of `add process` section

Comment: You need to add them before the `add al, bl`

Comment: I added them and it works, thank you so much for your help :)